# Create view that filters by group

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, view

Is it possible in SharePoint Online to have views based on the group the user is a member of? For example, if I assign user 1 to group A, and user 2 to group B, would it be possible for user 1 to see only tasks from a list that have a column that would match group A.

I tried creating a column that accepts "Person or Group", but I don't know how to filter a view for groups. I know that if we want to filter it for a user, we should put [Me]. Is audience targeting a solution? If so, how would I accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default view filter option doesn't allow filtering on **[Group]**. However, it might be accomplished by using SharePoint Designer.

You can check out this [article](https://anhvnn.wordpress.com/2017/08/18/sharepoint-online-filter-items-created-by-user-or-group-of-user-in-custom-list/).

The key is to add the [Where] clause to the View Filter Query (CAML)

```
<Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
    <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
</Membership>
```

For audience targeting, you can read [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-navigation-news-and-files-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293).